# using setter and getter for calculations

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception, null, getter-setter

I have this program in Java that was working fine. However today, although there are no errors in the program, I get the following message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at geometrycalculator.planeFigurePerimeter.rectangle(planeFigurePerimeter.java:12)
    at geometrycalculator.GeometryCalculator.main(GeometryCalculator.java:50)
C:\Users\gustavo\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
BUILD FAILED (total time: 8 seconds)
```

So on line 12 of the child class I have:

```
calculator.setPerimeter((length + width) * 2);
```

On line 50 of the main program I have:

```
perimeter.rectangle();
```

On the parent class I have:

```
public void setPerimeter(double newPerimeter){
        perimeter = newPerimeter;
    }
    public double getPerimeter(){
        return perimeter;
    }
```

For some reason the calculation is not performing in: `calculator.setPerimeter((length + width) * 2);`

The parent class is abstract, the child class extends from the parent class, that way I don't have to create the same variables on all the other child classes.

Comment: Please provide all of the relevant code so we can reproduce the error.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to get NPE is, your `calculator` object reference might not have initialized/`null`.

Check if it has been initialized properly before calling `setPerimeter` method

```
calculator.setPerimeter((length + width) * 2);
```

Comment: I have this in the class:  geometryFigures calculator;

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issue I was having was because I had the parent as the abstract class and couldn't access the setter and getter directly. I changed the parent class to be public and not abstract and it works now. Any suggestions on if I should change the parent class from public to private and/or have it be abstract are welcome. Im open to expand my knowledge on Java.